# How to get an oleObject's link location in Word using C# OpenXML

Tags: c#, .net, openxml, openxml-sdk

I just need to get the linked file's location instead of extracting the file.

In an Excel/Word/PowerPoint you can add an object as a link to another file, and I want to get the linked file's location.

In Excel I can use OpenXML to get the linked file's location by using ExternalRelationships. However it seems that PowerPoint and Word stores these file links differently and only in the oleObjects itself which are .bin files. I think the link is stored in the Ole10Native file after unzip the bin file but I don't think that is a great way to find the link. How can I get the link to the other file?

Example of getting the link from Excel

```cs
using (SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(filePath, false))
{
    WorkbookPart workbook = document.WorkbookPart;
    foreach (ExternalWorkbookPart externalWorkbook in workbook.ExternalWorkbookParts)
    {
        foreach (ExternalRelationship link in externalWorkbook.ExternalRelationships)
        {
            // link.Uri.ToString() is the path to the linked file
        }
    }
}
```